# importing all table data to from one schema to another schema

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a schema **SCHEMA1** which has 10 tables with data.
How can I copy **all table and its data** from **SCHEMA1** schema to **SCHEMA2** schema, it should have all **.sql** script and **data** to be inserted

I am using DBeaver workbench.

Comment: Backup, then restore?

Comment: Yes, I have more than 200 tables and it's growing, So I can explicitly specify tables, I there any way where copying to another schema @tadman

Comment: if you don't have tables in schema2 then you can use like that `create table schema2.tablename select * from schema1.tablename;` if you already have similar tables and have some data then use `insert into schema2.tablename select column_name1,column_name2,.. from schema1.tablename;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic sql query to achieve this.

**Query**

```
set @query = '';
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'alter table schema1.', table_name,' rename schema2.', table_name,';'
    ) separator ''
  ) into @query
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'schema1';

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

in SCHEMA2  you can create that 10 tables 1st then you can use

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA2.table1 SELECT * from SCHEMA1.table1
.........
in this way you can import others table data
```

Or You can use mysql workbench dump export, import functionality 
1. export SCHEMA1 then
2.import dump in SCHEMA2 
below link showing how to export and import mysql dump in mysql workbench

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html

Comment: I have more than 200 tables and it's growing, So I can explicitly specify tables, I there any way where copying to another schema @Zaynul

Comment: @ganesh 200 tables is not any matter for creating dump by using mysql workbench

Comment: @Ganesh : [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803448/importing-all-table-data-to-from-one-schema-to-another-schema/39803602#39803602)

Comment: @Ullas In this table name is mentioned. I have growable table I cannot explicitly mention tables.

Comment: @Ganesh : That's what I told you to [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803448/importing-all-table-data-to-from-one-schema-to-another-schema/39803602#39803602). I used dynamic sql query.